# How to select the nth child element from a table of parents with counts

Tags: sql, postgresql, parent-child

Suppose I have two tables:

```
create table parents (id integer, name varchar, child_count integer);
create table children (id integer, name varchar, parent_id integer);
```

Assume the parents:children ratio is about 1:1000.

And suppose `child_count` is updated periodically (or is available through a materialized view in PostgreSQL), for example using this update statement:

```
update parents p set child_count = pc.count
from (select p.id id, count(c.*) count
    from parents p join children c on p.id = c.parent_id
    group by p.id) as pc
where p.id = pc.id;
```

I want to find the nth child across all children, where children are sorted first by parent name, and then by the child name. Basically, I want this query:

```
select c.*
from children c join parents p on p.id = c.parent_id
order by p.name, c.name
limit 42 offset 42;
```

... except this is an expensive query requiring scanning through the children, but I know it can be done much more cheaply using the child_count field - at the risk of possibly being out of date, but I'm not worried about that.

Is there any way to write a query (preferably for postgresql) that uses the parent's child_count to select the nth child across all parents?

Or is there a better way of structuring the data? I'd consider using ranges (whether postgresql native or using two separate columns) except they seem difficult to update. And I may want to select the nth child using a different sort order (but always sorting using parents, then children).

My current best idea is to cache all the parents in memory, and use a limit / offset query after I've discovered the correct parent myself, but there may be a substantial number of parents too.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the `row_number` [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) (and see [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tutorial-window.html) and [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) too) might be exactly what you need:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (  SELECT  p.id AS parent_id,
                p.name AS parent_name,
                c.id AS child_id,
                c.name AS child_name,
                row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY p.name, c.name ) AS ordinal
        FROM    children c
                JOIN parents p ON c.parent_id = p.id
    ) AS x
WHERE x.ordinal = 42
ORDER BY p.name, c.name;
```

In fact, with the above query, you don't even need to retain the `child_count` column (tho you may want to for other reasons).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right; it's valid T-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server), which is my primary SQL dialect.

Comment: This selects the nth child of every parent, not the nth child overall for the concatenated list of children across all parents. However, you've given me interesting info to look over, and ideas for more queries, so +1

Comment: In particular, it looks like `sum() over` is relevant to my interests WRT making use of the `child_count` column, although I probably will end up caching at least the ids and counts of the parents in memory anyway. (In my real problem, there are grandparents, i.e. 3 levels, but no keys over 32 bits).

Comment: @BarryKelly see the updated code. In the `OVER` clause of the `row_number` function, I removed the `PARTITION BY` clause and added `p.name` to the `ORDER BY` clause.